# Method to check if a series of one variable is periodic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, periodic-functions

I have been solving differential equations by series solution method and I wanted to ask if there is a method to check if the series we get is periodic in its variable. In particular, if we get a solution for some ODE as

$$y \left( x \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$$

where $a_n$ is governed by some recurrence relation, then can we predict if the solution is

---

Edit:-

I have performed some try: If the function $y$ is periodic of period, say $p > 0$, then it must satisfy $y \left( x \right) = y \left( x + p \right)$. This, when substituted in series and then comparing the coefficients of equal powers of $x$, we get the following result for $n \geq 0$,

$$a_n = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty} \binom{k + n}{n} a_{k + n} p^k$$

If we add another condition of periodicity $y' \left( x \right) = y' \left( x + p \right)$, we get the same result for $n \geq 1$.

If we just cancel out the first term, we get the following result for every $n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace$

$$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty} \binom{k + n}{n} a_{k + n} p^k = 0$$

Now, from here what can we say about the coefficients $a_n$ so that the function $y$ is periodic?

---

Edit:-

I have been thinking and the above equation tells us that the series $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty} \binom{k + n}{n} a_{k + n} p^k$ converges. For that to happen, a necessary condition is that

$$\lim\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty} \binom{k + n}{n} a_{k + n} p^k = 0$$

for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So, if the recurrence relation for $a_n$ is known from the series solution method of differential equations, can we find some conditions so that the above limit holds true? In particular, I have the recurrence relation as $a_0, a_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ are arbitrary, $a_2 = 0$ and for $n \geq 1$ we get

$$a_{n + 2} = \dfrac{1}{\left( n + 2 \right) \left( n + 1 \right)} \left[ a_n - 2 \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]} \dfrac{\left( n - 2k \right) a_{n - 2k} \left( -1 \right)^k}{\left( 2k + 1 \right)!} - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]} \dfrac{a_{n - 2k} \left( -1 \right)^k}{\left( 2k \right)!} \right]$$

Can we find the rate of convergence of this recurrence relation and then comment on the limit mentioned above?

Comment: I think the only periodic functions with period $p$ defined by their Taylor series on $\mathbb{R}$ are $\sin (2 \pi x/p)$, $\cos (2 \pi x/p)$ and their linear combinations. If your function is supposed to be periodic and you know the period, then you can use Fourier series instead of Taylor.

Comment: That is not always true. $e^{\cos x}$ is also $2 \pi$ periodic. In general, functions of sine and cosine can be periodic under certain conditions.

Comment: You are right, my bad. However, all periodic functions can be represented by Fourier series with appropriate period. I would suggest using that. If an ODE defines a periodic function, then you should be able to find Fourier coefficients from it, using orthogonality

Comment: My first comment was meant specifically for functions globally defined by their Taylor series. I'm not sure which periodic functions except for $\cos$ and $\sin$ have that property

Comment: So, if I were to use Fourier series, how would finding the coefficients look like? For instance, suppose we consider a second order differential equation $y'' + p \left( x \right) y' + q \left( x \right) y = 0$.

Comment: Simply substitute $$y(x)=\sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty c_n \exp \left(\frac{2 \pi i n x}{p} \right)$$ where $p$ is your period. Then multiply by $\exp \left(-\frac{2 \pi i m x}{p} \right)$ and integrate from $0$ to $p$. If the equation, as well as your initial/boundary conditions allow for a periodic solution then you should get a neat system of equations connecting the coefficients. If you truncate the series like this $y(x) \approx \sum_{n= -N}^N c_n \exp \left(\frac{2 \pi i n x}{p} \right)$, you need to only solve $2N+1$ equations.